# C# Excel datarow compare value

Tags: c#, string, excel, datarow

Here's my problem:
I have an excel file which i run on a certain row.
I am trying to compare the datarow value with a string value. if it equals, i want to add the value of a close cell to access table.

I know only how to copy paste.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            database11DataSet.tblContacts.NewRow();
            foreach (DataRow r in dsContacts.Tables[0].Rows)
              {
                 string a = "123";
                 DataRow dr = database11DataSet.tblContacts.NewRow();


                 if (dr[0] == a) ///How to compare??
                 {
                   ///////
                 }
                  //// I want to write the value of a close cell to the access database.
                database11DataSet.tblContacts.Rows.Add(dr);
           }

                tblContactsTableAdapter.Update(database11DataSet);
        }
```

Im sorry if i am not clear. I can explain again if needed.
thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If the value in dr[0] is a string you can try:

dr[0].ToString().Equals(a)